# Display cell.textLabel.text from JSON response

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I need to display the `"href"` web address as the `cell.textlabel.text` in a `UITableView`.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**JSON:**

```
"grandfathers": [{
        "id": "60",
        "sons": [{
            "id": "30",
            "grandsons": [{
                "id": "10",
                "links": {
                    "api": {
                        "news": {
                            "href": "http://api.website.com/v1/family/grandfathers/sons/grandsons/10/news"
                        },
                    },
```

**@interface:**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *grandfathers;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *sons;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *grandsons;
```

**Table View:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"standardCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Grandfather *grandfatherLocal = [grandfathers objectAtIndex:0];
    Son *sonLocal = [grandfatherLocal.sons objectAtIndex:0];

    // Not sure what to do here to get to the "href" eventually
    // This was my best guess...
    Grandson *grandsonLocal = [sonLocal.grandsons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [grandsonLocal.links.api.news.href valueForKey:@"href"];
};
```

I'm not sure how to get to the nested data at that point.  (FYI I set up Models and am using RestKit, so thats the context for what I'm doing here.)

**EDIT:**
I'm getting nothing displayed in the table, and the error in the Output is just: "Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''"

**EDIT:**
Grandson Interface per request:

```
@interface Team : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Links *links;
+ (RKObjectMapping *) mapping;
@end
```

**EDIT:**
Alessandro answered my question perfectly, see below.  BTW, he went above and beyond to help me, I'm super greatful-

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly related - `cell` might be nil depending on your setup.  Have you registered the class / nib file for your cell?  From the docs: _"If no cell is available for reuse and you did not register a class or nib file, this method returns nil."_

Comment: valueForKeyPath:@"links.api.news.href" ?

Comment: @AaronBrager cell is not nil, but thanks for the heads up just in case it was

Comment: @MarcMosby thanks for the response.  Just tried your suggestion and didn't get anything working with variations of it-

Comment: and you did grandsonLocal valueForKeyPath and not grandsonLocal.links.api.news.href valueForKeyPath?

Comment: @MarcMosby Yup, I just tried it again to double check.

Comment: Peel your JSON apart one layer at a time.  NSLog each layer.  See json.org for the (very simple) JSON syntax, so you can interpret what you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `grandsonLocal` is fetched correctly, then I think you should just use

```
    cell.textLabel.text = grandsonLocal.links.api.news.href;
```

If this doesn't work, try to put a breakpoint in that line and inspect the content of `grandsonLocal` and of its properties.

Comment: `grandsonLocal` is fetching correctly because on the previous `UIViewController` I list all of the `id` associated with it in a `UITableView`... so for some reason I'm not sure how to map correctly from `links` all the way to `href`

Comment: Can you post the Grandson @interface? It should have a links NSDictionary property, or a links property pointing to something like a "Link" object

Comment: sure, I just posted the code.  You are correct, there is a `Links` property pointing to the `Links` object (which has a property `api` that points to `api` object, which has a property `news` that points to `news` object, which has `NSString` `href` property and has mapping of `href`)

Comment: Well, then using `cell.textLabel.text = grandsonLocal.links.api.news.href;` (the code that I posted in my answer) should work, is it?

Comment: It still seems to not be working, even though I understand what you're saying too. I can't figure out how to get this thing pinned down still, and I have no idea why

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the cell.textLabel.text line. Then use the debugger variable inspector (the panel on the left of the debugger log) to explore the content of grandsonLocal. Try to check if links contains something, if api contains something and so on. Maybe in this way we can find out what breaks the chain.

Comment: For grandsonLocal, it gives me the correct @ name associated with it.  I don't see anything for the variables after that-

Comment: For the cell.textLabel.text, it says highlighted in a green message "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1), address 0xc0109e6c)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29270/discussion-between-alessandro-orru-and-reez)